# What do I need to play Firefly: Echoes of War?

Tags: cortex-plus, cortex, firefly

I've recently found out about the yet unreleased Firefly RPG. What's currently available are [Echoes of War: Serenity Crew](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/118715/Firefly-Echoes-of-War-Serenity-Crew) and a [handful of adventures](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/browse.php?keywords=firefly%20echoes%20of%20war%20&x=0&y=0&author=&artist=&pfrom=&pto=). It is clearly stated that "Serenity Crew" is **necessary** for any of the adventures to be functional.

What's not clear to me is: is it **sufficient**? Besides one of the adventures and "Serenity Crew", what else do I **need** to play "Firefy: Echoes of War"?

I found no separate Cortex Plus core rulebook, so I'm hoping these two would suffice.

Comment: Also, since there's an adventure in both Cortex and Cortex Plus versions, I decided to include both tags.

Comment: The Firefly RPG has now been released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Firefly Echoes of War: Serenity Crew](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/118715/Firefly-Echoes-of-War-Serenity-Crew):

> **This release was first featured in Gaming in the 'Verse: Gen Con 2013 Exclusive. This title is the stand-alone version. You will need
>   this product, the Gen Con Exclusive, or the Firefly RPG corebook to
>   play Echoes of War adventures.**

In theory, this is true.  However, the reality of it is a bit more sketchy.  Of course, with the Firefly RPG you could play- it's not out yet, however.  Gaming in the 'Verse also had enough rules to play- it's just out of print.  Firefly: Echoes of War includes 2 files - one is a printer friendly version of the datasheets, and the other has more background- it's basically directly excised from the Gaming in the 'Verse book.  It describes what stats mean, and describes what the ship's stats mean.  It however, is missing any mention of the use of said stats other than what dice to roll.  There's a whole area on the intro to Cortex Plus that's in the Gaming in the 'Verse book that's not there.

What does that mean for playing?  You could get another Cortex Plus book and fudge it from there- Leverage comes to mind as the only one that's actually still available on Drive Thru.

It is possible that in the adventures there could be more information on actually how to run combat and how to take damage and such- but if there's not, then you're missing some basic Cortex Plus information.

Comment: These are my fears. I'll wait for someone else to chime in on what's on the adventures. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Core rulebook came out on April 2nd; with that, you have everything you need to play the game by itself. The book includes all the rules, the Crew Sheet, and a recap of all the Episode of the show and hints on playing them.

Unless you really want to play the Adventures from the Echoes of War line, you don't need any of them.